# Buffer coming out to be a circle

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-processing, buffer, road

I have been trying to make a buffer for the roads but the buffer is coming out to be a huge circle. Both the project coordinates and Shapefile coordinates are the same. Any pointers on how to solve that?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add some more information - examples, screenshots, etc. As it stands, your question has insufficient detail.

Comment: I have added images

Comment: How did you change the CRS of your data? Looking at the extent, it seems the unit of the data is still in the decimal degree.

Comment: What were the original CRSs of the two layers?

Comment: Before starting, I set the project CRS to EPSG: 32643, then I did those assigning coordinate thing in the georeferencing window, and in the transformation setting I put target CRS as EPSG: 32643 (And for each point I put CRS as EPSG: 32643).

Answer (score 3):

You have most likely **set** the layer CRSs to EPSG:32643 when you need to **reproject** the layer to EPSG:32643.

If you look at your scale in the second image above, it's 24:1 (ie 24cm on the map = 1cm on the ground!), which is clearly wrong. I loaded up the same area (using Bing Aerial Imagery) and the scale was around 1:5000.

Also, my co-ordinates are clearly in UTM, as expected. Your co-ordinates are in lat/lon displayed (incorrectly) as UTM.

[image]

The solution is to set the layer CRSs back to their default ones, and just change the CRS of the project to EPSG:32643. QGIS will handle the reprojection.

Alternatively, use the Warp (reproject) tool (for rasters) or Reproject layer (for vector layers) to correctly reproject the layers to EPSG:32643.

Comment: I have georeferred the image, so the default CRS would be the ones I set, right? Also, I kept the Project CRS to EPSG: 4326, and the same for the layer, and then created a shapefile for the road with CRS EPSG: 32643, and the buffer problem is solved, and the scale shown is also correct this time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your CRS, you must be using EPSG:4263, change it to UTM that should solve your problem.

[image]

[image]

I would personally export the layer and save it in a different CRS.

Comment: My CRS for the program is EPSG: 32643, basically it's in UTM, and the shapefile is in UTM as well.